# regex to get all number from a string?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like this:

```
AAAA 1 BBBB 2
```

I want to get all the number and return the result: `12`

I tried `\d` but it just get the first number.

In conclusion, I want to get all the number from a string in order then combine it to make a new number.

Comment: Use this `var result = 'AAAA 1 BBBB 2'.match(/\d+/g);`

Comment: that returns an "array", @HassanImam

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes after that OP has to use `join('')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract out all number from your string using `/\d+/g` and then join the result to get your new number.

```js
var result = 'AAAA 1 BBBB 2'.match(/\d+/g);
console.log(result.join(''));
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your question can be satisfied by just removing all non numeric digits from the string.  Then, you would be left with all numbers sandwiched togther.

```js
var input = 'AAAA 1 BBBB 2';
input = input.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
console.log(input);
```

Comment: This is a nice way to do it! Great!

Comment: `[^0-9]` == `\D` does it not? and I'd use `.replace(/\D+/g, '')` instead :p

Answer (score 1):

Just check this code i hope it will fulfil your condition.

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var str = "AAAA 1 BBBB 2 CCCCC 6 asghj6adcgf 7"; 
    var patt1 = /\d+/g;
    var result = str.match(patt1);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use parenthesis for grouping (\d) and execute it multiple times until nothing is matched.

```
const regex = /(\d)/g,
    str = 'AAAA 1 BBBB 2'

let match
while(match = regex.exec(str)) {
    console.log(match[0])
}
```

result

```
1
2
```